# Why mouseover event not dispatching for polyline in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've a complex flow where I've to attach mouseover event for every polyline on the map. The code for attaching the event is simple:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, "mouseover", function() {
    console.log('event fired');

});
```

But the event is attaching to few polylines and not to others. What might be the reason?

**Edit**

Following is some more code that is before the above code and used for defining polyline:

```
this.polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path : [fromPosition, toPosition],
    strokeColor : '#CCCCCC',
    strokeOpacity : 1.0,
    strokeWeight : 2
});

var polyline = this.polyline;
```

**Edit 05-Apr-2012**

Following is the code that creates problem, Please explain why it's happening and recommend any solution. Thanks

```
function Link(from, to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}   

Link.prototype.show = function() {
    this.line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path : [this.from, this.to],
        strokeColor : "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity : 0.5,
        strokeWeight : 6
    });

    this.line.setMap(map);    
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.line, 'mouseover', function() {
        this.line.setOptions({
            strokeOpacity : 1
        });
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.line, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.line.setOptions({
            strokeOpacity : 0.5
        });
    });
}

var links = [];
var link2 = new Link(new google.maps.LatLng(-3.5999999999999996, 23.4), new google.maps.LatLng(-4.5, 23.4)), link1 = new Link(new google.maps.LatLng(-3.5999999999999996, 23.4), new google.maps.LatLng(-3.5999999999999996, 18));
links.push(link1);
links.push(link2);

// I've a long list of links, so I'll prefer a loop
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].show();
}
```

JSFiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wasimbhalli/9bg6x/

Comment: try this http://lab.gmtplusone.com/google-maps/polyline-click-issue/

Comment: Can you post more code?  Is polyline global or declared within the context of something else?

Comment: Do the polylines overlap? Is the expected behavior that when two polylines overlap, the listener should fire for both polylines?

Comment: lines are not overlapping. They are shown in a loop and I'm simply adding listener but that doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: There may be a scope issue. What is `this`?

Comment: Then it should not attach to any polyline, but it attaches to some :s ``this`` is the current instance (created with the ``new`` keyword) of polyline

Comment: How many polylines are there when you notice it won't fire an event? Have you tried adding them one by one and testing them as they are added? Is there anything different about the polylines that don't respond?

Comment: I displayed only three polylines for testing and two of them never get an event attached :|

Answer (score 8):

> - **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbngxku9/

```
 var map;

 function initialize() {

   var mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(-3, 23),
     zoom: 5,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), mapOptions);

   var bounds = [];
   var bounds_group_1 = [new google.maps.LatLng(-3.5999999999999996, 23.4), new google.maps.LatLng(-4.5, 23.4)],
     bounds_group_2 = [new google.maps.LatLng(-3.5999999999999996, 23.4), new google.maps.LatLng(-3.5999999999999996, 18)];
   bounds.push(bounds_group_1);
   bounds.push(bounds_group_2);

   for (var i = 0; i < bounds.length; i++) {
     addPolylineSegment(bounds[i]);
   }
 }

 function addPolylineSegment(bounds) {

   // optionally you can put each polyline
   // segment into an array to later use...

   var polyline;

   polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
     path: bounds,
     strokeColor: "#0000FF",
     strokeOpacity: 0.5,
     strokeWeight: 6
   });

   polyline.setMap(map);

   // attach event listener to each segment...
   google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseover', function(event) {
     this.setOptions({
       strokeOpacity: 1
     });
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseout', function(event) {
     this.setOptions({
       strokeOpacity: 0.5
     });
   });
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Perfect, why do I forgot to try everything I can attach to [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?

Comment: @ Evhz May: the code does not attach events to everything... it just do it for each bound segment (in this case 2 segment) in order to be accessed separately...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm trying to keep the solution close to your code. The key was changing both listener's this.line.setOptions to this.setOptions:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.line, 'mouseover', function() {
        this.setOptions({
            strokeOpacity : 1
        });
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.line, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.setOptions({
            strokeOpacity : 0.5
        });
    });
```

I've seen a similar case with markers in another question. I believe `this` inside the function() already refers to the first argument of addListener(), in this case, `this.line`, so you are covered just saying `this`. Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zfFsD/

The other change I made was putting the links[] code in my initialize(). Wish you the best!

Comment: Oh,, you got it right, I don't have the right demo code. But, unfortunately, I'm using ``this.setOptions`` in my actual code :s or as I shown in the first code snippet in my question, nothing is written to console for 'some' polylines :|

Comment: You have made spaghetti out of your Polylines :D

Comment: @wasimbhalli Create `jsfiddle` with 'right demo code', and we'll see what's the problem. Could you please?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a scope problem.

change

```
this.line.setOptions
```

with

```
this.setOptions
```

Firebug and console.log() are your friends :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this using the method described below. If I understood you correctly, the loop in which you attach a listener to a polyline does not in fact get "attached" to the polyline that way, but instead, you need a new class instance that contains the polyline and the listeners. This way, each polyline gets it's own listener.

Please, see the explanation below.

**EDIT 5.4.2012**

Here's also a crude JSFiddle demonstration of the code in action. [Link to JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ferian/KMYBs/2/)

```
function initialize() {

    // initialize Google Maps canvas normally

    var polylines = [];

    // Data set of the polylines you want to present on the map, 
    // e.g. [ { lat:"...",lon:"..." }, ...]

    var polylineData = [{ ... }] 

    for ( i in polylineData ) {
         var line = new google.maps.Polyline({ 
             path: [/*coordinates as google.maps.LatLng objects*/] 
         });

         // Create a new myPolyLineClass instance that contains the polyline data
         // and push it to polylines array.

         polylines.push(new myPolyLineClass(line));
    }

    // Set all the polylines and their individual listeners on map

    for ( i in polylines) {
        polylines[i].line.setMap(map);
    }
}

function MyPolylineClass(lineData) {
    this.line = lineData;

    // + all other data you want the polylines to contain

    // Add listeners using google.maps.event.addListener to all class instances
    // when they are constructed.

    // for instance:

    google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'mouseover', function() {
            line.setOptions({ [options you want to set when area is hovered 
            and selected] });
    });

    // Add listeners also for when polyline is not hovered anymore, respectively,
    // and other methods you might want to call when polylines are being interacted with.
};
```

Hope this helps!

Cheers

Comment: I've updated the code, please use it in your example and test. Thanks!